# Trigger in SQL Server 2012 to Update Account Balance

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a CustomerMaster table which has a column named AccountBalance. Each customer (uniquely identified by CustomerId in CustomerMaster) can have 0,1 or many transactions in a ClientTransaction table, which has a column called Amount (indicating the amount of the transaction). I want to create a trigger on the ClientTransaction table for INSERT, UPDATE, AND DELETE to maintain the AccountBalance. I have tried defining the trigger below; when, I delete only one row, it updates the AccountBalance correctly; however, when I do a DELETE ClientTransaction to delete all records, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ClientAccountBalanceUpdate]
   ON  [dbo].[ClientTransaction]
   FOR INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if not exists (select 1 from Inserted) -- Delete trigger
        update CustomerMaster set AccountBalance = AccountBalance - D.Amount from CustomerMaster inner join Deleted D on CustomerMaster.CustomerId = D.CustomerId 

    if not exists (select 1 from Deleted) -- Insert Trigger
        update CustomerMaster set AccountBalance = AccountBalance + I.Amount from CustomerMaster inner join Inserted I on CustomerMaster.CustomerId = I.CustomerId

    if  exists (select 1 from Deleted) and exists (select 1 from Inserted) -- Update trigger
        update CustomerMaster set AccountBalance = AccountBalance - D.Amount + I.Amount from CustomerMaster inner join Inserted I on CustomerMaster.CustomerId = I.CustomerId inner join Deleted D on CustomerMaster.CustomerId = D.CustomerId

END
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are looking only at 1 of all rows that are being deleted, you need to `SUM` all rows from `DELETED` before you set it to be updated. Same issue will arrive if more than 1 row is Inserted or Updated

Comment: @SaUce yes, that was my hunch, and I had tried to do a sum but must have been doing it wrongly, because it was still not working correctly. Could you give an example? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, your issue is that your code only works if there is one transaction. Here is an example of what your code could look like to handle multiple rows in an insert.

```
If Not Exists (Select 1 From Deleted) -- Insert Trigger
    Update CustomerMaster 
    Set AccountBalance = AccountBalance + 
        (
        Select Sum(I.Amount)
        From Inserted I 
        Where CustomerMaster.CustomerId = I.CustomerId
        )
    From CustomerMaster
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is fired only once ( when the first row is inserted, updated or deleted ).

If you `insert`, `delete` or `update` more than 1 row, your trigger will not be fired a next time unless next 2 conditions are met ( in the given order ):

1. all of the queues ( inserted, deleted and updated ) have been emptied
2. after inserted and deleted and updated are all empty, another row is inserted, deleted or updated.